# Building Qt Base failed (PhantomJS)

Tags: qt, phantomjs

Currently running Windows 10 vs2013 developer cp.

I'm trying to build PhantomJS from [this](https://github.com/SeNaP/phantomjs/tree/2.1) fork but is failing on building Qt Base. I followed all the steps described on the [ofical site](http://phantomjs.org/build.html).

The Qtbase is their [own version](https://github.com/Vitallium/qtbase/) I think it's a fork of Qt5.

The last log lines are the following ones:

```
 "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Release
        cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -O2  -MT -Zc:strictStrings -D_HAS_EXCEPTIONS=0 -MP -GR -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -DUNICODE -DWIN32 -DQT_BOOTSTRAPPED -DQT_LITE_UNICODE -DQT_NO_CAST_TO_ASCII -DQT_NO_CODECS -DQT_NO_DATASTREAM -DQT_NO_LIBRARY -DQT_NO_QOBJECT -DQT_NO_SYSTEMLOCALE -DQT_NO_THREAD -DQT_NO_UNICODETABLES -DQT_NO_USING_NAMESPACE -DQT_NO_DEPRECATED -DQT_NO_TRANSLATION -DQT_CRYPTOGRAPHICHASH_ONLY_SHA1 -DQT_NO_CAST_FROM_ASCII -DQT_BUILD_BOOTSTRAP_LIB -DQT_BUILDING_QT -D_CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS -D_USE_MATH_DEFINES -DQT_ASCII_CAST_WARNINGS -DQT_MOC_COMPAT -DQT_USE_QSTRINGBUILDER -DQT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS -DQT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x040800 -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_NO_GRAPHICSVIEW -DQT_NO_GRAPHICSEFFECT -DQT_NO_STYLESHEET -DQT_NO_STYLE_CDE -DQT_NO_STYLE_CLEANLOOKS -DQT_NO_STYLE_MOTIF -DQT_NO_STYLE_PLASTIQUE -DQT_NO_PRINTPREVIEWDIALOG -DNDEBUG -I. -I..\..\3rdparty\zlib -I..\..\..\include -I..\..\..\include\QtCore -I..\..\..\include\QtCore\5.6.2 -I..\..\..\include\QtCore\5.6.2\QtCore -IC:/phantom/src/qt/qtbase/include/QtXml -IC:/phantom/src/qt/qtbase/include/QtXml/5.6.2 -IC:/phantom/src/qt/qtbase/include/QtXml/5.6.2/QtXml -Itmp -IC:\phantom\src\qt\3rdparty\libicu\include -IC:\phantom\src\qt\3rdparty\libxml\include -IC:\phantom\src\qt\3rdparty\openssl\include -IC:\phantom\src\qt\3rdparty\zlib\include -I..\..\..\mkspecs\win32-msvc2013 -Fo.obj\release\ @C:\Users\xavi\AppData\Local\Temp\nm8087.tmp
qdom.cpp
..\..\xml\dom\qdom.cpp(35) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'qdom.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\VC\BIN\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.

ERROR: Failed to build PhantomJS! Building Qt Base failed.
```

I can provide the full log if necessary.

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: I know it's not what you ask, but FWIW I was able to build SeNaP's fork for linux. (Just an idea to consider)

Comment: @Vaviloff I need to build it for windows. Did you do anything out of the ordinary in order to compile it?

Comment: Nope, I didn't, but it was almost 2 years ago (building for Win).

Comment: So it **IS** possible to build this fork on Windows currently, that's nice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just came across a very similar error when trying to compile phantomjs by accident with VS2015.  Solution was to use full version of VS2013 (I don't know if CTP will give you the correct _MSC_VER,) do a clean build (I just re-cloned) and to make sure to do the git submodule init and git submodule update commands before running the build script (so basically following directions!)

Not sure if this will help you but hopefully it does.

Comment: The build script automatically executes submodule init and update. I manage to build it after like 3 hours of fiddling with it on a clean VM with VS2013.